# Story about an astronaut in cryogenic sleep to serve as “living memory” who eventually returns to an abandoned Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have been trying for years to track down the details of a short film or television series episode I saw many years ago. I would have seen it aired on Canadian television around 1988, possibly 1990 at the very latest. It is possible that this was a French-language dub of something that wasn’t originally shot in English.

The story features an astronaut who is sent to orbit the Earth in hibernation. At a regular interval (100 years, perhaps) he is set to wake up to be interviewed by people on Earth about what life is like in the 20th century.

The first time he wakes up, his broadcast from space is met with much excitement. The second time, however, people on Earth remember who he is but don’t really care so much. Each time he wakes up, things get worse: the people he contacts are downright belligerent, and eventually no one even understands English.

Finally, he fails to contact anyone at all, and this is when he’s had enough and decides to abort the mission. He returns to Earth only to find it completely deserted. He wanders alone in an empty city. Eventually, he comes across a robot, or some sort of talking machine with which he’s able to have a conversation. The machine informs him that all humans left the Earth decades ago. The end. (I think.)

I’m aware that this story features several popular tropes: astronaut in hibernation, things aren’t right when an astronaut returns to Earth, last man on Earth. . . However, I don’t think I’ve seen the idea of waking up at regular intervals to serve as a witness to the past in other stories.

Because of the story and probable date of broadcast, I thought it could have been a Twilight Zone (Second Series) or an Amazing Stories episode. However, I can’t find anything that matches.

Does anyone have any idea what this is?

Comment: Sounds like a reversed plot of "The Voyage That Lasted 600 Years" by Don Wilcox (1940, http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60790). But the protagonist of the story, an historian, is unfrozen once every hundred years to both teach the newborn aboard the generation ship about Earth's customs and check that they didn't degenerate.

Comment: Thanks, there’s a definite similarity. The time spans are also in the same range, I think. If I remember correctly, the astronaut in my story woke up five times.